# Restrict access to Salesforce REST Resources

Tags: rest-api, permissions, profile

The Salesforce org I am working on needs to restrict access to the Salesforce's REST Resources from Lightning Platform REST API. (for example `/services/data/vXX.0`)

From my research I understood that you need `API enabled` permission in order to access these services, so if I want to restrict them I would just have to deactivate this checkbox from the profiles.

The problem is that I still need access to all the **custom** Rest APIs, which can be invoked only if the users have the same permission. `API enabled` is supposed to allow API calls to **any** Salesforce API, whether *custom* or *standard*.

Can you please help me with that? I was not able to find a clear answer so far.

Comment: I'm not clear. Do your users not have separate profiles from yourself? Preferably, if they were on separate profiles you could have different settings?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I am the admin and yes, they have a differrent profile. I want to restrict their access to the Lightning Platform REST API for them, but not the access to the custom APIs that are developed. My user will not be affected.

Comment: What are your custom APIs? Apex REST web service methods?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves they are just custom REST resources developed to retrieve object records, make certain validations. So yes, Apex web services

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a permission now that will allow you to access custom Apex REST services while not being able to access the standard REST API:

[image]

Comment: I have tried to enable only this permission (without API enabled) and it works. I thought that if you do not have API enabled, the custom Apex Rest Services cannot be called. But they can. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem @RoxanaElenaCismaru, this is a very useful permission that I myself had been waiting for a long time. Glad it helped you